# How to get my last TWEET into an NSString in my iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, twitter, nsxmlparser

There are a bunch of tutorials online about how to use xmlparsers or what not to bring an entire twitter feed into a UITableView. Thats not what I need. I only want ONE tweet. The most recent twitter update.

So, would some of you geniuses please show me in detail how to get my last (most recent) TWEET into an NSString in my iPhone app?

Comment: You need to create a connection to the twitter server, and use some API call to retrieve this last tweet.
The tweet will be retrieved as raw data probably and you will have to create a string out of that data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short: exactly the same as all those tutorials that you've read except you pass the `count` parameter to the [`statuses/user_timeline` REST method](http://apiwiki.twitter.com/Twitter-REST-API-Method%3A-statuses-user_timeline).

Answer (score 0):

Ohh, this is complicated, not so easy, I show you the steps:

- Make the request to the api (synchronous or asynchonous)
- Handle the Authentication Challenge for authenticated request
- Get the data, call the parse method of the parser
- Handle the delegation methods of the nsxmlparser
- Manually handle the DidStartElement, DidFoundCharacters, DidEndElement to get the first status you want, assign the string value to a variable when it founds the characters.

That's all you need to do ;)

Good luck.